# Is there a way to block copying an email signature's company logo?

Tags: email

This may be a pointless exercise, but after searching web for answers, I have not really come up with any answer.  Is there a way to block the copying of a company logo when sent in an email signature?  Supposedly this can be done, but the only 'sort-of' answer I found was using Information Rights Management, and I am unsure how or if that really works, or if its worth the hassle on an SMB (40 email users) kind of budget.

I realize that if someone REALLY wants to copy a logo for ill intent, they will do so no matter what.  Take a screen shot, take smartphone picture, etc.  But for a client who is asking, I'd like to know if its possible regardless so I can furnish some sort of legitimate response.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

D

Comment: The better question may be found if you ask why you are trying to prevent coping the signature. Are you looking to authenticate whether emails are coming from valid accounts? If so, there are answers for that. I think you answered your own question with the screenshot or picture notes comments.

Comment: I mean, I google "companyname logo" and obtain logos that way. So why are you trying to protect this via email?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to prevent. Anyone can get your company logo any one of at least a hundred different ways. What's at risk? Why are you worried about this? This sounds a bit like tilting at windmills to me.

Comment: Please do not send your company logo in an email signature. It's clutter in a number of ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no reasnoable way to block it.

> they will do so no matter what. Take a screen shot, take smartphone picture, etc.

As you already knew, this is eventually the way it works even for the most computer-illiterate users. Take the Windows Snipping-Tool and go for it.

But images in signatures will also be sent directly to the recipient in most cases, so he can simply save the file on the disk. And if the image is not embedded, then it can be saved from the webpage it is placed.

> Information Rights Management

Yeah, well. Information Rights Management is overkill (even that is an understatement) and way to expensive. And every receipient needs to agree to use that. If they don't, they don't see the image in the first place.

Basically it's like that: If the receipient sees the image, he can save it to disk because you have no control over his computer or what he is doing with it.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  I knew the answer already, but wanted to know if it was possible.  IRM is overkill, and my client is satisfied with that answer.  The REASON this came up is of course, someone mentioned to my client that they should block copy of the logo so that no perp can create fake letterheads with it, etc. Thus, the client assumed it could be done.  I had or wanted a more definitive answer as to why it cannot be done, or could not be done without the overkill of IRM.  Anyways, I appreciate your comments as it verified my conclusions.  D

Answer (score 4):

No, it simply can not be done.

You should **really** explain this to your customer: he has to understand that, when he put *any* content on the internet, you basically lose control over it. You can use the very same example you wrote above (screenshot, photo, etc) to explain it the basic problem.

Obviously, this does **not** means that he can not (and sometime, he *should*) put a discaimer stating that all images (and/or other contents) are copyright of its company.